# Why am I losing type inference on events when I use index signatures?

Tags: typescript, dom-events

Based on the type passed to `addEventListener` the compiler knows what parameter the event handler should be, in this case, a `KeyboardEvent`

```ts
const foo = document.getElementById("foo");

if (foo !== null) {
  foo.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
    console.log("hey", e);
  });
}
```

However, in this code block below, despite me even type casting it in the constructor. The Union `HTMLElement | HTMLInputElement` in the [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) breaks the `addEventListener` inference.

```ts
interface DOMElements {
  [index: string]: HTMLElement | HTMLInputElement;
}

class Baz {
  $: DOMElements;

  constructor() {
    this.$ = {
      bar: document.getElementById("bar") as HTMLElement,
    };
  }
}

const baz = new Baz();

baz.$.bar.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => { 
// compiler now sees e as type Event instead of KeyboardEvent
  console.log("hey", e);
});
```

if I try to explicitly type it with

```ts
baz.$.bar.addEventListener("keyup", (e: KeyboardEvent) => {
  console.log("hey", e);
});
```

I get the following compiler error.

```
Argument of type '(e: KeyboardEvent) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EventListenerOrEventListenerObject'.
  Type '(e: KeyboardEvent) => void' is not assignable to type 'EventListener'.
    Types of parameters 'e' and 'evt' are incompatible.
      Type 'Event' is missing the following properties from type 'KeyboardEvent': altKey, charCode, code, ctrlKey, and 17 more.
```

Here's my tsconfig

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["ESNext", "DOM"],
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "strict": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

Both types in the union support keyboard events and even if they didn't the type cast should solve that. Looking forward to some insight.

Check out the error in [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-violet-v20v9f?file=/src/index.ts)

Comment: [I'm not sure I can reproduce what you're seeing](https://tsplay.dev/N9O5jW).  Does it?  If so could you explain what the problem is?  If not, then could you [edit] to make a [mre]?

Comment: @jcalz I Made an error the first event was meant to be `keyup` otherwise your sandbox that you sent actually is my desired behavior. I'll edit and add a link where i'm getting the bug

Comment: Still works for me... check the `e` parameter in the callback: https://tsplay.dev/wR071m

Comment: @jcalz [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-violet-v20v9f?file=/src/index.ts) should show it, it goes away if you stop using a union type but i can't get why that would matter.

Comment: It does indeed matter. If `v` is a union type then `v.method()` can only be invoked in certain ways supported depending on [the explicitly implemented support for calling union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-3.html#improved-behavior-for-calling-union-types). `addEventListener` has multiple generic overloads, so I'm not surprised the union would be weird.  Please [edit] the post with plaintext demonstration code (a sandbox link is a nice supplement but it does not suffice as a [mre]) to make it a properly posed Stack Overflow question.